# Lattice program in R potentially causing an error with loading other packages and libraries

Tags: r, lattice

I keep getting this error message in R when loading new packages and libraries (see below). I think it has something to do with downloading the lattice package a few days ago but I have no idea how to uninstall this package or if that is even the issue.

```
library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sp’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘lattice’
Error: package ‘sp’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘raster’ was built under R version 3.5.3 
2: package ‘sp’ was built under R version 3.5.2
```

I tried using `remove.packages("lattice")` but I am getting this message:

```
remove.packages("lattice")
Removing package from ‘C:/Users/schubba/OneDrive - Emory University/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘lattice’
```

Comment: try removing it from your file structure and reinstalling

Comment: How do you remove it from your file structure?

Comment: Going into File Explorer or equiv, locating where your R library is kept and deleting the folder lattice if it exists.

Comment: I found the folder lattice and deleted it. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error message: > library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sp’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘lattice’
Error: package ‘sp’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘raster’ was built under R version 3.5.3 
2: package ‘sp’ was built under R version 3.5.2